# react-scripts: command not found in react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

Im running a react-app on localhost and this error popped out. I have installed the correct dependencies with npm install, but for a reason i don't know it doesn't find the command react-scripts.

[image: The error displayed in the console]

Comment: can you post your package,json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to meet you.

Please check your node version.
After setup your node.exe.

And set the below contents to your package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Then please execute the command line.
"npm start"

Best regards.

Comment: Please **check** and **vote** about this answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Mr. Charlie.
Could you please check and vote about my answer?

Comment: [Done, regards]